# Why the slow screen redraw under certain circumstances in React Native

Tags: react-native

Usually simple `ListView` rows are rendered nearly instantly. Sometimes, however, the rendering goes slowly, to a point where you can see the screen being drawn. What causes this?

I first noticed it in an app I'm building to try out React Native, but was also able to reliably reproduce in the react-native repository [Movies example](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/tree/master/Examples/Movies). To reproduce:

- Open the Movies example project and run in the iOS simulator
- Search for a common word (e.g. "fast")
- Delete one character a time.
- Notice that once the data is fetched, the screen updates instantly.
- Now search for a nonsense word (e.g. "asdf")
- Delete one character at a time.
- Notice how a few times the rows of the search result list appear almost one-at-a-time. It's quite visibly slow compared to the instant redraw of the first query.

You should see something like this:

[image: animated gif showing screen redraw comparison]

I noticed that, from react's perspective, the `ListView` is finished rendering before it's fully visible on the screen. I found this out by passing a callback to the `setState` call that causes `ListView` to re-render. The call back logs a message to the console, and the message appears slightly before the full screen is painted.

I would very much like to know if others have observed this and if it's avoidable. It's happening quite often in my app and makes the live-search feel pretty slow.

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried adding 'initialListSize' on the ListView? I found adding it improved performance quite a lot, if you know the minimum list size beforehand.

Edit - from the docs:

> Rate-limited row rendering - By default, only one row is rendered per event-loop (customizable with the pageSize prop). This breaks up the work into smaller chunks to reduce the chance of dropping frames while rendering rows.

Try adding pageSize={10} for example to the ListView

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I tried it but it didn't seem to help (much).

Comment: @DrewGoodwin Actually what fixed it for me was adding pageSize{10} for example on the ListView, this is the number of items to be rendered per event loop

Comment: @hosainnet - I noticed a significant difference when I used `pageSize={10}` ... As I was rendering 10 objects each time.